# Showing info from a Sqlite database in 3 different QListWidget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyside6

My objective is to show a kanban table by day, so the user could save their pending, in process or completed tasks for each day in the calendar. My program look as follows:

[image: UI for my program]

Every list is a QListWidget, where the user can add a new pending task by right clicking over them or move the tasks from the "Pendientes" list to the "En proceso" list or the "Completadas" list.
Now, for saving the task for every date of the QCalendarWidget, I'm trying to use a sqlite database that looks like this:

[image: sqlite database]

where the "tareas" column shows the tasks, "lista" shows a number corresponding to each of my three QListWidgets (0 = "Pendientes"; 1 = "En proceso" and 2 = "Completadas") and "fecha" shows the date. I'm able to show every task in the corresponding list by date just fine with this function, but only the tasks that I added directly in the Sqlite Browser:

```
def updateTaskList(self, date):
    self.lista_pendientes.clear()
    self.lista_enprogreso.clear()
    self.lista_completadas.clear()
    
    db = sqlite3.connect("todo.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    query = "SELECT tarea, lista FROM tareas WHERE fecha = ?"
    row = (date,)
    results = cursor.execute(query, row).fetchall()
    for tarea, list in results:
        item = QListWidgetItem(tarea)
        if list == 0:
            self.lista_pendientes.addItem(item)
        elif list == 1:
            self.lista_enprogreso.addItem(item)
        elif list == 2:
            self.lista_completadas.addItem(item)
```

But when I try to save the tasks that I added from my program it doesn't save the changes:

```
def saveChanges (self):
    db = sqlite3.connect("todo.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPython()
    for i in range(self.lista_pendientes.count()):
        item = self.lista_pendientes.item(i)
        task = item.text()
        query = "UPDATE tareas SET lista = '0' WHERE tarea = ? AND fecha = ? "
        row = (task, date,)
        cursor.execute(query,row)
    db.commit()
```

In this function I'm trying to save only the tasks that are in the "pendientes" list, by assigning the index 0 to those tasks, but to no avail. What could I do to save the tasks from the three QListWidgets in my database?

**EDIT-SOLVED**
After experimenting a bit I founded an easier solution: to use three different tables in my sqlite database for each type of task. That way I can save each task individually without worrying about the list column.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in variables. and which part of code is executed. Maybe it never runs `for`-loop and it never write it.

Comment: Please read [example]